# Any book between Apostol and Montgomery?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, book-recommendation

I studied Analytic Number Theory by Apostol (Introductory and Advanced vols) and I learnt very good! And because of that studying of the first two chapters of [Montgomery's book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/multiplicative-number-theory-i/4E45519B26115AEEA4839C6C38206ACD) was possible but it is very hard or sometimes impossible to study from chapter 3 onward. I chose the mentioned Montgomery's book because of amazon reviews but I stuck in it!

Is there any intermediate book between those Apostol and Montgomery? or any advice for better reading not-simple-written Montgomery's book?

Comment: You could try Davenport's Multiplicative Number Theory, though I'm not sure it's any easier than Montgomery's.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, mostly I have difficulties with a chapter on "sieve methods". Is there is simple book to study such topics? Davenport's book is same level as Montgomery's.

Comment: Personally, I skipped Chapter 3 in the first reading and read other topics. As results of Sieve do not appear many times in latter part, you may do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a simple book on sieve methods – sieve methods just aren't simple – but Cojocaru and Murty, An Introduction to Sieve Mehods and their Applications, is worth a look. It's in the London Math Society's Student Texts series, which is encouraging. The preface recommends Chapters 1 through 5, and 7, for a senior level undergraduate course, says Chapters 6, 8, and 9 are at the graduate level, and Chapters 10 and 11 are at the seminar level.

There's a 20-page chapter on sieves in Bateman and Diamond, Analytic Number Theory, and 25 pages in De Koninck and Luca, Analytic Number Theory.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some [course notes](https://pub.math.leidenuniv.nl/%7Eevertsejh/ant-mastermath.html) on Sieve methods from a master's course given by Prof. Lola Thompson in Leiden University. I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You can study the wonderful book [Opera de Cribro](https://bookstore.ams.org/coll-57) by John Friedlander and Henryk Iwaniec. The book has got excellent reviews and the authors are the leading experts in Sieve methods!

On a lighter note: Here is an exposition on
[Number field sieve](https://www.ams.org/notices/199612/pomerance.pdf)
written by C. Pomerance.

Comment: As a researcher in the field, Opera de Cribro is a much more challenging read than Montgomery-Vaughan.